# Blazor Web Assembly - XmlDocument.load() so slow (file size of 100mb)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, xmldocument

Good afternoon all,

I have an WPF c# based application which interrogates many xml files (in region of 100mb) and it works fine. Just like a console app, it takes less than 2 seconds to load a 100mb xml file into memory via

Xmldocument xmlDoc = new Xmldocument();
XmlDoc.load(filePath);

In my wildest attempts to rebuild my application in something more modern such as Blazor Web Assembly, I can’t understand why the same load statement takes 45 times slow to load file?

Using InputFileChangeEventArgs, I can get the file selection from InputFile, encapsulate into a MemoryStream and load the stream into an Xmldocument but it is so very slow. Why is this?

Is this likely to be the MemoryStream causing the issue, the .load() method or simply the 100mb file takes time to read before it can proceed?

Just curious as it’s all .Net, so wondering what’s different with Console and WPF compared to Blazor?

I haven’t ventured down the Blazor Server just yet, was wondering if I could keep it client side only for now. Will all web based apps (ASP etc) have this slowness issue or could it be a bug?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Suppose you want the nice web based gui but it needs to process data within a file of 100mb. This probably isn’t considered large in this day an age? Should I stick with my WPF based app as it performs well enough. I was only trying to modernize and learn something new but maybe web app isn’t fit for my needs… cheers

Comment: Henk, would you happen to know if this performs any better using Blazor Server? Thanks